# How to make Discord.py get how MANY users reacted with a specific emoji?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a poll command in Discord.py but want at the end the bot to send a list of users that reacted with 1️⃣ and another list of people that reacted with 2️⃣.
This is my code so far:

```
async def poll(ctx, q1, q2, time : int):
    await ctx.send(f"React with 1 to vote for **{q1}** and with 2 to vote for **{q2}**\n**Poll Lasts for {time} seconds**")

    poll = discord.Embed(title = "Poll", color = discord.Color.blue())
    poll.add_field(name = f"{q1} 1️⃣", value = "᲼᲼᲼᲼᲼᲼")
    poll.add_field(name = f"{q2} 2️⃣", value = "᲼᲼᲼᲼᲼᲼")

    msg = await ctx.send(embed = poll)

    r1 = await msg.add_reaction("1️⃣")
    r2 = await msg.add_reaction("2️⃣")

    await asyncio.sleep(time)

    await ctx.send("Times up! **Poll Closed**")

    new_msg = discord.utils.get(client.cached_messages,id = msg.id)

    users1 = await r1.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users1.pop(users1.index(client.user))

    users2 = await r2.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users2.pop(users2.index(client.user))

    em=discord.Embed(title=f'Votes for {q1}', description=" , ".join(user.name for user in users1),color = discord.Colour.blue())
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

    em=discord.Embed(title=f'Votes for {q2}', description=" , ".join(user.name for user in users2),color = discord.Colour.blue())
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reactions'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Message.add_reaction` returns `None`, you can't use these two lines

```
r1 = await msg.add_reaction("1️⃣")
r2 = await msg.add_reaction("2️⃣")
```

Easiest approach would be to fetch the message again with the updated reactions

```py
message = await ctx.send("Whatever")
await message.add_reaction("1️⃣")
await message.add_reaction("2️⃣")

await asyncio.sleep(10)

updated_message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message.id)

users1, users2 = [], []

for r in updated_message.reactions:
    print(f"{str(r)} was added {r.count} times")

    if str(r) == "1️⃣":
        users = await r.users().flatten()
        users1.extend(users)

    elif str(r) == "2️⃣":
        users = await r.users().flatten()
        users2.extend(users)

# `users1` and `users2` are lists of users that reacted with `1️⃣` and `2️⃣` accordingly
```

#### Reference:

- [`Messageable.fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)
- [`Message.reactions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20reactions#discord.Message.reactions)
- [`Reaction.count`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20reactions#discord.Reaction.count)
- [`Reaction.users`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20reactions#discord.Reaction.users)

Comment: So I changed the code but now when the time ends and the 2 embeds with who voted for what are sent it only says My Bot voted for  option1 and My Bot voted for option2

Comment: What intents have you enabled? Did anyone else also react?

Comment: So it doesn't let me send my new code bcs it's too large, I'll just Add Answer my code. And yes, 2 other people reacted. Then I tested it again only me reacting.

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep` must be BEFORE `await ctx.channel.fetch_message`

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped:)

Comment: Ok I will! But I have one last problem, if I vote for 2 it doesn't say anything, if I vote for 1 it says I voted for both of them.

Comment: Hm, I don't quite understand at all

Comment: Oh nevermind! It was a stupid mistake, I messed up the lists name! Thanks btw it helped a lot! Also how do I accept an answer?

Comment: Simply click in the tick that's next to the answer (left upper side)